# Node js, display post for certain x of time and then remove it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to display my blog articles for x amount of time and then remove it from the page, not delete it from database. In this case i would like to display my articles for about 48-72 hours. I am not entirely sure how to go about this.

Comment: In its current form, this question is much too broad.  Consider revising your question to be more specific:  What does this have to do with node.js?  What blog platform are you using?  How are your articles stored?  What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a queue or cronjob will achieve your goals.
I would go for a queue as it will give you more flexibility as per your use case. While creating a blog post add one job to the queue with the delay of 48-72 hour whatever you want and then write soft delete function in process function of that job.

In the following snippet, I have used [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) package and scheduled a job at the post creation time. In the post database keep one field as `isDeleted`. Now when this job is processed set that as true and in fetching posts write query to fetch those post which has isDeleted flag false

```
createPost(data) => {
    // your create job logic
    queue.create('deletepost', {
        postid: '123'
    }).priority('high').delay(48*60*60*100).save();
}

queue.process('deletepost', function(job, done){
  // WRITE LOGIC TO SET isDeleted FLAG TRUE IN DATABASE
});
```

This is pseudo code. I haven't tested it but it's almost similar.